# MDX Expression to Filter Calculated Measure for members that have ROE > 12%

Tags: filter, ssas, mdx, olap, measure

I have a calculated measure called Return on Equity and another called Net Income and a dimension called customers.  I would like to see the combined Return on Equity for all customers that have a net income greater than $1,000.  How do I create an MDX expression do show that?

Answer (score 0):

The title and the explanation don't really match... over 1000 and over 12% ROE not exactly the same, i'll try to answer the explanation.

You did not provide any Cube structure so i'll give you a generic example:

```
WITH
SET CustomerOver1000
AS
FILTER (
    [Customer].[Customer].MEMBERS,
    [Measures].[Net Income] > 1000
)
MEMBER ROECostumerOver1000
AS
SUM(CustomerOver1000,[Measures].[ROE])
select
    {ROECostumerOver1000} on 0
from [myCube]
```

Comment: you could move the named set into the expression for ROECostumerOver1000? (or would that impact the performance?)

Answer (score 0):

We can also use HAVING to filter the measures similar like SQL 
**HAVING [Measures].[Net Income] > 1000**

Comment: HAVING is performed once all calculations have occured so I don't believe it would be a good idea in this circumstance?